# JQGrid While Column reordering - issue with header display

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using JQGrid and I want column drag and drop feature for this I enabled set sortable = true option. Now the problem is when I have scrollbar and trying to reorder the last columns by dragging the UI of header is mess up as shown below. When I click on country column this column placed at other end.

[image]

Comment: Please, include always the exact **version of jqGrid**, which you use (can use), and the **fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). It's required if you report a bug. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa3.htm), which uses free jqGrid 4.13.6. Could you reproduce the problem on the demo? You can include the link to another demo, which can be used to reproduce the problem, which you report.

Comment: You use "free-jqgrid" tag, which description can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info). Free jqGrid is the fork, which I develop. The last release of the product: 4.13.6. Do you really use the "free jqGrid" of some other jqGrid?

Comment: Hi, Oleg, i am using free-jqGrid 4.13.6 and this issue is reproducing when we have the horizontal scrollbar and trying to drag columns. As you can see in the above image where when I start to click on the say last columns (country in this case) its repositioned on left side of the screen but expected where the cursor is.

Comment: Try [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa3-scrollbar.htm), which has the scroll bar. Sorry, but I can't guess what you do. You should just provide *your demo*, which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed my issue... Sorry its my bad... I was mess up with some css of other components.

**Thank you Oleg for helping me and also for wonderful grid component.**